# Regex for finding a distinct group of letters

Tags: java, regex

Im searching a regex that matches a group of size n which consists of distinct letters inside the context of the group
it should for example match

```
aabcddbc => abcd
or jkjklmnqrrqkn => klmn
aabcb => should not match
```

so the distinctness of the letters is only specified inside the group. Not for the global String if that makes sense.

A solution like:

```
(?:([a-z])(?!(.*\1))){4}
```

will check if the letter is distinct in the whole string and not only in the group

So far I came up with this:

```
([a-z])(?<=^.*\1#MISSING#)([a-z]){4}
```

My plan is:

Match start of group and save it as \1

Match next letter (\2) if the letters before do not include \2 between beginning of the group and size n.
At this step I am failing. I managed to find the beginning of the group by `^.*\1` but then how do I check if the next 3 letters only incldue \2 once?
a check like `[^\2]{3}\2` or `\2[^\2]{3}` doesn't work because \2 could be anywhere inbetween the group.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `([a-z])(?!\1)([a-z])(?!\2|\1)([a-z])(?!\3|\2|\1)[a-z]` https://regex101.com/r/hKikrW/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes excatly. But this is needed for a size n and not just 4. Every example I mentioned was just an example. Maybe that was a bit unclear

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is for this year's advent of code? I wrote a [function](https://github.com/LtSalt/AoC-2022-1/blob/main/code/06.qmd) that returns a regex similar to what [@The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) proposed, for a given length n. The code is in R but might help you nonetheless:

```R
n_unique <- function(n) {
  if(n == 1) return("(\\w)(?!\\1)")
  
  make_regex <- function(out, input) paste0(out,"(?!\\", input, ")")
  
  regex <- accumulate(seq(2, n - 1), make_regex, .init = "(\\w)(?!\\1)") %>% 
    paste0("(\\w)") %>% 
    paste0(collapse = "")
  
  return(regex)
}

n_unique(4) #(\\w)(?!\\1)(\\w)(\\w)(?!\\1)(?!\\2)(\\w)(\\w)(?!\\1)(?!\\2)(?!\\3)(\\w)
```

This function relies heavily on `accumulate`, a reducer function which saves it's intermediate returns.

You basically 1) glue your growing negative lookaheads together, then 2) glue a final capture group to the end and 3) finally collapse your string vector into a single regular expression. You'll also need to give your reducer function the correct starting value (`.init`).